# Openlayer 2 :Can I delete Vector layer or change its z-index when mouse hover on it?

Tags: gis, openlayers

I am adding 2 vector layers.

```
this.mapport.vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
this.mapport.inside_vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector();
map.addLayer(this.mapport.vector);
map.addLayer(this.mapport.inside_vector);
```

and I am adding features of inside_buffer like

```
inside_vector.setZIndex(999);
var inside_feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(inside_geom, null,this.inside_buffer_style);
this.mapport.inside_vector.addFeatures(inside_feature);
```

and vector layer 1 features as

```
var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geom, null, this.buffer_style);
this.mapport.vector.addFeatures(feature);
this.request_select(feature, options, event, layers, behavior);
```

initially I want to show user inside_vector layer but when user will hover over it Its z-index must be 0. Can I do it in openlayer2 ? till now I tried 4,5 examples on stack overflow but they are about features not about layer itself. So my basic task is to show inside_buffer downside the vector layer

Comment: Can you please add the links to the answers from here you have tried?

Comment: @Markus I wrote this programm  my self. Its basically JSTS library to draw buffer . I am facing issue that , when I draw 2nd buffer , 1st one come under  the 2nd one , Can I change sequence on hover ?

Comment: and @Markus I tried this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537671/openlayers-control-z-index-between-layer-with-and-without-selectfeature   but answer Jsfidde are not available :(

Comment: Sorry, I just try to help you improving your question. You should add those answers to the your question and explain why they did not work.